# How is memory managed during tensor transformations?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Even if the question involves TensorFlow, I will use normal math terminology to describe my question.

Let's say that

- I have a matrix `W` of dimension `n x k`
- An input vector `x` of size `1 x k`
- I need to compare `x` to each element in `W`

After reading some code examples, the way I do it now is as it follows (`n = self.nNodes`, `k=self.inputShape`):

```
inputShape = (10,)

W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform( (nNodes, ) + inputShape, 0.0, 1.0, dtype=tf.float32), dtype=tf.float32, name='W' )

x = tf.placeholder(self.__datatype, inputShape, name='input')

x_M = tf.expand_dims(x, 0, name='x_m')

x_MM = tf.tile(x_M, (nNodes, 1), name='x_mm')

spatDiffs = tf.subtract(x_MM, self.W)
```

It seems to be - but I am not sure - that, after a while, TensorFlow has some difficulties in managing the memory (especially on the GPU) since the `expand_dims` and `tile` operations return *new* tensors.

Is there any way to allocate a tensor for `X_MM` (as I do for `W`) and **copy** the input value `x` into each element of `X_MM`. In this way the memory for `X_MM` would be allocated only once.

Is there an "atomic" instructions for copying a vector, line by line, into another (a sort of tiling without allocating new memory)? Should I use a TensorFlow iterator for obtaining this?

More in general, should I worry about memory management with TensorFlow? It seems to me it is an important topic, but cannot find any relevant info on the documentation and all of the examples I see use operators that allocate new memory.

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow manages memory for you automatically. You should just write your computation in the natural way and let Tensorflow manage buffers for you.

For example, Tensorflow automatically reuses the input buffer of some operations for the output, without you needing to do anything. I don't know whether that happens for the specific operators in your code.

If you are having problems with a specific Tensorflow program running out of memory, please provide a detailed, runnable, self-contained reproduction. It's impossible to say what's going wrong without more information.

Hope that helps!